# including a IIFE module in bundle

Tags: javascript, commonjs, iife, rollupjs

I'm having problems understanding how to bundle iife modules with rollup.js. 
The module I'm trying to load is defined like...

```
;(function (sax) {
    sax.parser = function (strict, opt) { return new SAXParser(strict, opt) }
    sax.SAXParser = SAXParser
    sax.SAXStream = SAXStream
    sax.createStream = createStream
    [...]
})(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? this.sax = {} : exports)
```

this is my `rollup.config.js`:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

export default {
  input: 'index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'build/foo.js',
    format: 'umd',
    name: 'foo'
  },
  moduleContext: {
    'node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js': 'window'
  },
  plugins: [
    globals(),
    nodeResolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true
    }),

    commonjs({
      include: [
        'node_modules/**',
      ],
      namedExports: {
        'node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js': 'default'
      },
      ignore: [ 'conditional-runtime-dependency' ]
    }),

    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
  ]
};
```

And my code is importing the dependency with...

```
import sax from "sax";
```

But `rollup -c` is failing with:

```
[!] Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

In commonjs namedExports you have to use the string you use for importing, not the file directory:

```
commonjs({
  include: [
    'node_modules/**',
  ],
  namedExports: {
    sax: ['default']
  }
}),
```